# Splitting mixed content nodes on particular regex match with xslt 3

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

My simplified input looks like this:

```xml
<stuff>
    <p>CAPITALWORD is part of <i>mixed</i> content.</p>
    <p>ANOTHER is <i>here</i> but it's not the only one. SOMEWORDS are <i>mixted up</i> in the same
        paragraph. SOMETIMES even <i>multiple times.</i></p>
</stuff>
```

Now, my goal is to split paragraphs on each full-caps word. I thought I would go for grouping text starting with at least two capital letters like this:

```xml
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="true"></xsl:output>
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="text()[matches(., '[A-Z]{2,}')]">
    <xsl:element name="p" >
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:element>  
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

but this won't work because I'm dealing with mixed content rather than strings only. So I get this:

```xml
<stuff>
   <p>CAPITALWORD is part of <i>mixed</i> content.</p>
   <p>ANOTHER is <i>here</i>
   </p>
   <p> but it's not the only one. SOMEWORDS are <i>mixed up</i> in the <i>same</i>
   </p>
   <p>
        paragraph. SOMETIMES even <i>multiple times.</i>
   </p>
</stuff>
```

instead of the desired output:

```xml
<stuff>
    <p>CAPITALWORD is part of <i>mixed</i> content. </p>
    <p>ANOTHER is <i>here</i> but it's not the only one. </p>
    <p>SOMEWORDS are <i>mixed up</i> in the <i>same</i> paragraph. </p>
    <p>SOMETIMES even <i>multiple times.</i></p>
</stuff>
```

I will be most grateful for tips on how to achieve the desired output.

Comment: Can a full-cap word be in italic or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is a two step transformation, the first step uses analyze-string on text nodes to wrap your capitalized word into an element, the second step then can easily use group-starting-with on those wrapper elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:variable name="capitalized-marked-up" as="node()*">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="markup-capitalized"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$capitalized-marked-up" group-starting-with="capitalized-word">
      <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </p>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="capitalized-word">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode name="markup-capitalized" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template mode="markup-capitalized" match="text()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., '\p{Lu}{2,}')" mode="wrap"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="wrap" match="fn:match">
    <capitalized-word>{.}</capitalized-word>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Martin! This works without a hitch. The only bit I don't understand —  and would very much like to —  is what's the role of `match="fn:match"` in `<xsl:template mode="wrap" match="fn:match">`. I can't quite figure out what it does concretely here, yet the template with a mode requires a match attribute.

Comment: Text nodes are processed with `analyze-string` in `<xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., '\p{Lu}{2,}')" mode="wrap"/>`, that function returns elements named `match` in the function `fn` namespace for the matched items so the template `<xsl:template mode="wrap" match="fn:match">` processes the result of the `analyze-string` to wrap matches in a wrapper element `capitalized-word`.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two approaches to this. One is to convert all the information to a node structure by adding markup to the text, and then process it as a tree of nodes using grouping mechanisms and the like. That's what @MartinHonnen has done. The other is to convert all the information to text, for example by converting `<i>italic</i>` to `{italic}`, and then process it using regular expressions (typically `xsl:analyze-string`), finally converting `{italic}` back to`<i>italic</i>` as a post-processing step.

I would usually use the first technique, but if the only markup that occurs within the mixed content is a single element type (`i`) with no attributes, then you could consider the second.

An `xsl:for-each-group` is never going to split text up into fragments, which is what you seem to be attempting to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Michael for the additional explanation!